# Dealloc a pointer(*mut u8)

Tags: pointers, rust, allocation

I have created a ptr using alloc function

```
let layout = Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(1024 * 8 , align);
println!("Size {}, Align {}", layout.size(), layout.align());
let ptr = alloc(layout);
```

Now, I have converted this ptr to Vector using from_raw_parts().
After that I am passing this vector using ffi after forgetting at vector using forget(vec).
After that I receive ptr, len and capacity from ffi and than I wanted to dealloc that memory.

```
dealloc(vv.as_mut_ptr(), layout);
```

Is using delloc method for this use case is right?
How can I verify that the memory is actually dellocated? Is there any other way to do this deallocation of memory.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I verify that the memory is actually dellocated?

Rust `nightly` supports LLVM's `asan` functionality. It is an address sanitizer that checks for those things.

Note that this only works on Unix, Windows is currently not supported.

To activate it, install the `nightly` toolchain.
Then (for address resolution) install `llvm`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y llvm
```

Then all you need to do is run it with:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo +nightly run
```

For example, running the following code gives me:

```
rustuse std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};

fn main() {
    type VecElement = u64;
    let size = 1024;

    let layout = Layout::from_size_align(size * std::mem::size_of::<VecElement>(), 64).unwrap();

    let mut my_vec = unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(layout.size(), layout.align());
        println!("Size {}, Align {}", layout.size(), layout.align());
        let ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut VecElement;
        Vec::<VecElement>::from_raw_parts(ptr, 0, size)
    };

    my_vec.push(10);
    println!("{:?}", my_vec);

    unsafe {
        let ptr = my_vec.leak().as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;
        // dealloc(ptr, layout)
    }
}
```

```
Size 8192, Align 64
[10]

=================================================================
==9815==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 8192 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x5639279f54c7 in posix_memalign /rustc/llvm/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145:3
    #1 0x563927a42329 in std::sys::unix::alloc::aligned_malloc::ha31ca2931b3311a0 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/sys/unix/alloc.rs:97:23
    #2 0x563927a42329 in std::sys::unix::alloc::_$LT$impl$u20$core..alloc..global..GlobalAlloc$u20$for$u20$std..alloc..System$GT$::alloc::h8c999cb61b93cc7a /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/sys/unix/alloc.rs:22:13
    #3 0x563927a42329 in __rdl_alloc /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/alloc.rs:378:13
    #4 0x563927a1fe77 in rust_tmp::main::h6751a6125ac6d734 /home/martin/work/rust-tmp/src/main.rs:12:19
    #5 0x563927a283ca in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h3f2ab14fa827b4ba /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
    #6 0x563927a1f764 in std::rt::lang_start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hd3473a8235573380 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/rt.rs:145:18
    #7 0x563927a3cd9e in core::ops::function::impls::_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$F$GT$::call_once::hcd03e0aeba5cfb12 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:280:13
    #8 0x563927a3cd9e in std::panicking::try::do_call::h2dbc2d91fe9b324b /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
    #9 0x563927a3cd9e in std::panicking::try::ha8bdfaa383f0ed33 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
    #10 0x563927a3cd9e in std::panic::catch_unwind::ha58e9af879223892 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #11 0x563927a3cd9e in std::rt::lang_start_internal::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h56456e42fba96b18 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:48
    #12 0x563927a3cd9e in std::panicking::try::do_call::h2bc188e30e56674d /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
    #13 0x563927a3cd9e in std::panicking::try::hc5e32e9b04c0821c /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
    #14 0x563927a3cd9e in std::panic::catch_unwind::h8f69e6799c52cea0 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #15 0x563927a3cd9e in std::rt::lang_start_internal::hd1476181c5102217 /rustc/40336865fe7d4a01139a3336639c6971647e885c/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:20

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 8192 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

However, running the correct version that deallocates gives me:

```rust
use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};

fn main() {
    type VecElement = u64;
    let size = 1024;

    let layout = Layout::from_size_align(size * std::mem::size_of::<VecElement>(), 64).unwrap();

    let mut my_vec = unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(layout.size(), layout.align());
        println!("Size {}, Align {}", layout.size(), layout.align());
        let ptr = alloc(layout) as *mut VecElement;
        Vec::<VecElement>::from_raw_parts(ptr, 0, size)
    };

    my_vec.push(10);
    println!("{:?}", my_vec);

    unsafe {
        let ptr = my_vec.leak().as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;
        dealloc(ptr, layout)
    }
}
```

```
Size 8192, Align 64
[10]
```

No error. This shows that it does indeed deallocate correctly.

---

## WARNING

What you are doing is dangerous. You have to manually ensure that the vector actually gets deallocated through your `dealloc` function. There are zero compiler checks that you actually do this. This is a behaviour called [unsound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

Possible solutions:

- Provide a newtype wrapper that exposes only a sound subset of the `Vec` API for your usecase and ensures proper deallocation.
- Use the nightly [`Vec::new_in()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new_in) and [`Vec::with_capacity_in()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity_in) methods that allow you to provide a custom allocator. Although that does mean that your crate now requires the `nightly` compiler.

Answer (score -1):

STOP! STOP DOING THIS!

Vectors automatically allocate and deallocate memory, you don’t need these unsafe tricks.

Just use `Vec::new` or `Vec::with_capacity`.

```rust
let _my_vec = Vec::<u8>::new();
```

Comment: Actually, I need to allocate memory aligned to 512(it can be something else too(power of 2)). Thats why I am doing this.
Doing,
`let _my_vec = Vec::<u8>::new();`
Doesn't guarantee that the memory will be aligned.

Comment: In this case, you probably don't want to create `Vec` at all, since you'll then have to ensure that it will never grow (and therefore never reallocates).

Comment: I agree with @Cerberus. You most likely want to store it in a custom struct that implements `Deref` to get a slice to the memory

Comment: @Cerberus I need it to be a vector for by bussiness logic, Also the size of vector will never change or groww.

Comment: @Rusting_It Which business logic? As you probably don't push or pop items if you say the size won't change or grow. If you don't, what's the business logic of a vector that a slice can't provide?

Comment: @Finomnis My business logic don't involve pushing or poping init. 
Note : Capacity was assigned when pointer was created(which will be sufficent for my use case), although the length will change in my business logic which won't call reallocete method of vector.