# Avoid cycle Arc references without Weak in Rust

Tags: rust, automatic-ref-counting

I know that the data inside an `Arc` is stored in heap, and when two objects have `Arc` reference to each other, they would not be dropped automatically by compiler. The following code shows this case.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, sync::Arc};

impl Drop for Data {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("data {} drops here", self.x);
    }
}
pub struct Data {
    pub x: usize,
    pub next: Option<Arc<RefCell<Data>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let data1 = RefCell::new(Data { x: 42, next: None });
    let data2 = RefCell::new(Data { x: 53, next: None });
    let ptr1 = Arc::new(data1);
    let ptr2 = Arc::new(data2);
    ptr1.borrow_mut().next = Some(ptr2.clone());
    ptr2.borrow_mut().next = Some(ptr1.clone());
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

The output is just a line of `Hello, world!`, and no drops happen here.

That's becase even the pointers `ptr1` and `ptr2` are dropped at the end of the `main` function, the reference counters of `data1` and `data2` are still `1`, not decresed to `0`.

This seems like the *cycle Arc* which mentioned in Rust Programming Language, and it recommand us to use `Weak` to solve the problem.

However, when I want to drop it, I can replace `Data.Some(Arc<RefCell<Data>>)` with a `None`, that would drop the data.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, sync::Arc};

impl Drop for Data {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("data {} drops here", self.x);
    }
}
pub struct Data {
    pub x: usize,
    pub next: Option<Arc<RefCell<Data>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let data1 = RefCell::new(Data { x: 42, next: None });
    let data2 = RefCell::new(Data { x: 53, next: None });
    let ptr1 = Arc::new(data1);
    let ptr2 = Arc::new(data2);
    ptr1.borrow_mut().next = Some(ptr2.clone());
    ptr2.borrow_mut().next = Some(ptr1.clone());
// =========================================
    ptr1.borrow_mut().next = None;
// =========================================
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

The output is :

```
Hello, world!
data 53 drops here
data 42 drops here
```

So, in some way, Can I avoid all the cycle references in `Arc` without `Weak` and build some data structures just like maintaing a three node which contains its parent and children ?

Comment: You can't avoid the cyclic references if you want to store both parent and child. But as you say, you can still just create the cycles, and e.g. have an `unlink` function that walks your entire tree and sets all the parents to `None`. Though I'm not sure what the benefit of that would be, over just using `Weak` for just one of parent or children.

Comment: Mandatory read if you work with linked lists: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the address sanitizer as a debugging tool; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876508/dealloc-a-pointermut-u8/73877869#73877869) of mine for more details. I know this doesn't solve your problem, I just thought you might want to know that such a tool exists.

Comment: What is the reason of *not* using `Weak`?

Comment: The primary advantage I see to avoiding `Weak` is having a static guarantee that the referent exists. A `Weak` conceptually behaves kind of like a nullable pointer while an `Arc` behaves like a non-nullable one. (Whether this guarantee is worth the cost of a potential memory leak is up for debate, of course. Also, `Option<Arc<_>>` makes that advantage moot.)